# Select first record of a column using LINQ ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, linq

I got one table having fields like `Id`, `Smid` and `AdditionalComment`. I have multiple rows for same `Smid`, but `AdditionalComment` data appears only in first row. Please find below for the table structure

```
Id     |      Smid       |    AdditionalComment
-------+-----------------+-----------------------
 1     |        2        |       price 4.50 
 2     |        2        |
 3     |        2        |
 4     |        4        |       price 5.00
 5     |        4        |
```

and so on.

Find my code below

**CODE**

```
objlist.SMInfoId = smid.ToInt();
var comment = objlists.GroupBy(x => x.AdditionalComments).Select(g => g.First());
if (comment != null)
{
  al.Add(comment);
}

Session["arrayList"] = al;
```

Thank You in advance.

Comment: May I ask, what do you want to get as the result from your table?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I just want to get the additionalComment for the given Smid. For eg, if I give Smid =2 , it should display 'price 4.50'. Hope you understand. Thank you

Comment: Hi All, I tried all the below given codes, but none of them works for me, returns null value.

Comment: Hi - I'm pretty sure that both my suggestions below will put the value 'price 4.50' into the variable `comment` when `smid` is 2. Is this what you need?

Comment: @Merenzo, I tried both, but unfortunately didn't work out

Comment: @Merenzo, the variable obj returns null and Smid is integer type. I know both set of your codes are right, even my code that is  var comnt = (from cmm in objLists where cmm.SMInfoId == 1 select cmm.AdditionalComments).FirstOrDefault(); works fine in other pages, but I am not sure why it shows null in this page.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to find the comment for a specified `Smid`: so you could query for the object with `Smid` == (your number) and with an `AdditionalComment` entered.

So, probably something like this:

```
var obj = objlists.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Smid == smid && x.AdditionalComment != null);
var comment = (obj != null) ? obj.AdditionalComment : null;
```

Or if you specifically need to find the row matching `Smid` that has the lowest `Id`:

```
var obj = objlists
    .Where(x => x.Smid == smid)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .FirstOrDefault();
var comment = (obj != null) ? obj.AdditionalComment : null;
```

Comment: @user3824021, does the variable `obj` get populated with an object when you try either of these cases? And what is the type/value of your variable `smid`?

Answer (score 0):

try following code:

var result1 = dt.tbluserinfos.GroupBy(u => u.nm).First();

Answer (score 0):

Try this : ( *But AdditionalComment data appears only in first row* )

```
  var obj = objlists.Where(x=>x.AdditionalComment!="");
```